# Detailed dimensions of the Colosseum

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture

I know that the Colosseum is about 189x156 meters, and 48 meters high, but I am having trouble finding any information on the dimensions of each of the 4 rows of seating. To be exact, where each row starts/ends. I can't seem to find anything other than very basic information on the dimensions of the structure.

Comment: Are you looking for the height and depth of the seats, or a count of how many rows are in each section, or both? I browsed http://mathsforeurope.digibel.be/amphi.htm but have not checked any of the works cited.

Comment: I am starting to realize there isn't that much info on this, so either or both is great. Link looks useful. Haven't read whole thing but I'll look more in depth soon.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tribunesandtriumphs.org/colosseum/dimensions-of-the-colosseum.htm
This link appears to provide information on seat dimensions, arch heights of the 4 rows etc. 
Unfortunately, it didn't cite its primary sources.

Comment: Given that it is (largely) still extant, they might be simple first hand measurements and thus without any other sources.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't have the radius of the seating sections, but it does give the heights, which might be enough.